# When to use @ServerEndpoint vs @Controller in Java spring boot framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Can someone point out the differences between the 2 and when it is appropriate to use which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a class annotated by **@ServerEndpoint** is registered to a server-side WebSocket endpoint and every time the corresponding endpoint's WebSocket is connected to the server, its instance is created and managed by JWA implementation.

Classic controllers can be annotated with the **@Controller** annotation. This is simply a specialization of the **@Component** class and allows implementation classes to be autodetected through the classpath scanning.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

`@ServerEndPoint` is an annotation for the web socket, and `@Controller` is an annotation for the web. (Similarly there is `@RestController`.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this article can help:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support

**@ServerEndpoint**: If decorated with **@ServerEndpoint**, the container ensures availability of the class as a WebSocket server listening to a specific URI space

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/chat/{username}")
public class ChatEndpoint {
----
}
```

**@Controller**: If decorated with **@Controller** annotation is an annotation used in Spring MVC framework (the component of Spring Framework used to implement Web Application). The @Controller annotation indicates that a particular class serves the role of a controller. The @Controller annotation acts as a stereotype for the annotated class, indicating its role. The dispatcher scans such annotated classes for mapped methods and detects @RequestMapping annotations.